# What is wrong with the FROM clause in this MS Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have created a query in MS Access, but it doesn't work; it throws a somewhat generic error, instead:

> Syntax error in FROM clause

What is the problem in this query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM ((adsoyad 
    LEFT JOIN fatura 
        ON adsoyad.[gsm number] = fatura.[gsm number]) 
    LEFT JOIN base 
        ON adsoyad.[gsm number] = base.[gsm number]) AS t
```

Comment: quick guess just looking at it, you look like you're missing a second close parenthesis before the `as` - EDIT: on second thought, maybe not.

Comment: Remove `As T` what did you intend that to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use an alias (`As T`) in that way. An alias should either refer to a subquery, a field or a table. You're trying to use an alias on multiple joined tables.

Either remove the `As T`, or wrap your FROM section in a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   
    (SELECT * FROM 
         ((adsoyad 
         LEFT JOIN fatura 
                ON adsoyad.[gsm number] = fatura.[gsm number]) 
        LEFT JOIN base 
               ON adsoyad.[gsm number] = base.[gsm number])) AS t
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use parentheses here, and you should put a name to your tables.

I think like this it should work:

```
SELECT a.*,
       f.*,
       b.*
FROM adsoyad a
   LEFT JOIN fatura f
      ON a.[gsm number] = f.[gsm number]
   LEFT JOIN base b
      ON a.[gsm number] = b.[gsm number]
```

I didn't test it, though.

Comment: Access will put the () back in